# How to remove a class in header row?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, class

i'm in a Wordpress environment. I need to hide the "middle" and "bottom" rows of the header, so i gave a class "hide" to all rows, but here it is the problem: i need to remove the "hide" class from the "top" row so, with CSS, i can hide only the "middle" and "bottom" rows using the "hide" class.

How do i remove the "hide" class from the "top" row?

[image: Header rows inspection]

This is the modify i did to add the class "hide" (builder_header_renderer.php):

```
    $result = '<div class="hide" ' . blocksy_attr_to_html($row_container_attr) . '>';
    $result .= '<div ' . blocksy_attr_to_html(array_merge([
        'class' => $container_class
    ])) . '>';
```

Comment: Why not just `#header [data-row=middle], [data-row=bottom] { display:none }` in the css

Comment: @mplungjan i put   .blog #header [data-row=middle], [data-row=bottom] { display:none }      because i want that the two rows disappear ONLY in the blog page (so .blog class page)... but there is a problem:  the two rows disappear from ALL pages, and not only on the blog page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this strictly using JS, you could use the following in a script.js file in your child theme:

```
if(document.body.classList.contains('blog')){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('header#header>div')).forEach((item, index) => {
        if(index > 0){
            item.classList.add('hide');
        }
    });
}
```

In the functions.php file in your child theme, you can add this to include your script.js in your theme.

```
function mytheme_child_enqueue_scripts () {
    wp_enqueue_script('script-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/script.js', '', null, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_child_enqueue_scripts');
```

If you do this using JavaScript, make sure the following three prerequisites are met:

1. Do not add the `.hide` class in PHP.
2. When it isn't added in PHP, verify that the right header items have the `.hide` class added to them by `script.js`.
3. Target it in CSS using `header#header .hide { display: none; }`

If JS is not a strict requirement for achieving this, @mplungjan has the simplest and most performant approach in a comment to your question, although to adapt it to your requirements about the blog page, use this to achieve what you're looking to do:

```
body.blog #header [data-row=middle],
body.blog #header [data-row=bottom] {

    display:none

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213462/discussion-on-answer-by-syedmh-how-to-remove-a-class-in-header-row).